# Actionscript 3.0: Calling events only once and automatically remove them

Tags: actionscript-3, events

```
var Local:LocalConnection=new LocalConnection();
Local.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,function(event:StatusEvent):void{
 // This stuff should only be running once
});
```

There can be many listeners applied, so only this should be removed. So basically after this event have been dispatched, there can be another listener for the same instance of LocalConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
Local.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,function(event:StatusEvent):void{
  IEventDispatcher(event.currentTarget).removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can** remove anonymous event handlers **inside of that anonymous event handler**, as you always have a reference to the current function.

```
var Local:LocalConnection=new LocalConnection();
Local.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,function(event:StatusEvent):void{
    // This stuff should only be running once
    Local.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, arguments.callee);
});
```

There is no other native way to cause an event listener to fire only once, the listener must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it is nearly always better to avoid anonymous functions in flash:

```
var local:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
local.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);

function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void{
    local.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);
}
```

Also the convention is to use lowercase letter for the beginning of a variable.